# Invisible reCaptcha with Contact Form 7

Tags: contact-form-7, invisible-recaptcha

I'm using CF7 and Google's reCaptcha. I've gotten keys but am not sure if that's all I needed to do to integrate it. I know that if I add `[recaptcha]` to my form that it enables the one you interact with but that's not what I want. How do I test to see if it's working if I can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this guide: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Apart of the basic, you need to indicate how the button interact with the form using a "callback" function. For example, if the user pass the captcha, activate the send button.